# WCF CreateMessage from custom body xml

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following code:

```
string body = "<custom xml>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(body);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);
if (writer != null)
{
  doc.Save(writer);
  writer.Flush();
  writer.Close();
}

stream.Position = 0;
XmlReader rd = XmlReader.Create(stream);

Message output = Message.CreateMessage(msg.Version, msg.Headers.Action, rd);
output.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(msg);
output.Properties.CopyProperties(msg.Properties);
```

When I try to use the message I get the following error:

> hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 2.

Any idea why? And what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Well, `<custom xml>` isn't well-formed xml fort starters?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string body = "<?xml version='1.0'?><custom></custom>";
```

First of all, you often need the `<?xml version='1.0'?>` header, and as Marc G. already mentioned, your `<custom xml>` is not valid XML; first of all, XML tags cannot contain spaces, and second of all the opened tag is never closed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ignore the xml content. I just added dummy content to make the post shorter. The xml is valid and the problem is not the xml. Remember it is xml that is inserted into the envelope body. The <?xml version='1.0'> is not required.